# Understanding that both $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\ln(y+1)}$ and $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}$ is equal to $1$.

Tags: calculus, limits

**Question:**

I want to understand that both:

$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\ln(y+1)}$ and $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}$

is equal to $1$ using algebraic manipulations and standard limits (not L'Hopital's rule or series expansions).

**Reasoning:**

First of all is seems logical that when we switch the numerator and denominator that the limit still would converge to the same value. But is this always true?

In this particular case i tried to prove it but my result were the following:

$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1}{y}\ln(y+1) = \ln(y+1)^{\frac{1}{y}} = \ln(e) = 1$

$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\ln(y+1)} = \lim_{y\to 0} y(\ln(y+1))^{-1} =$ ??? $= \ln(e) = 1$

Comment: Note that $\ln(1+x)\leq x~\forall~x\in (-1,\infty)$ with equality iff $x=0$. Since $f(x):=\ln(1+x)-x$ is decreasing in the neighbourhood of $x=0$ (can be verified by computing $f^\prime(x)$), we can conclude that $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$. Hence, the two limits can be seen as $\lim\limits_{y\to 0}\frac yy=1$.

Comment: For the second limit couldn't you say the following?
$$\lim_{y\to 0}{\frac{y}{ln(y+1)}}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{1}{\frac{ln(y+1)}{y}}}=\frac{1}{ln(y+1)^{\frac{1}{y}}}=\frac{1}{ln(e)}=1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that when $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \ell$ and $\ell \neq 0$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{1}{f(x)}= \frac{1}{\ell}$.

**Proof**:

Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$. Then, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{1}{f(x)} \stackrel{*}{=} \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} 1}{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}= \frac{1}{\ell}.$

Here, since $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}=1 \implies \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\ln(y+1)} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.$

---

$*$ Generally, when $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = b\neq 0,$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and equals to $\displaystyle \frac{\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)}=\frac ab. $